# Timeout ao tentar acessar um serviço rest HTTPS via PHP

Tags: php, rest

Estou tentando acessar um serviço rest que está em um servidor HTTPS via PHP e está retornando timeout. Se eu pegar a URL e colocar no browser abre.
Estou utilizando o Httpful (http://phphttpclient.com/), já utilizei outras bibliotecas e ocorre o mesmo erro.
Agora quando acesso um serviço rest que está em um servidor HTTP funciona.

Abaixo o código que estou utilizando

```
$url = "https://api.github.com/users/nategood";
echo "<br>{$url}<br>";
$response = \Httpful\Request::get($url)
        ->strictSSL(true)
        ->send();
echo "<br>";
var_dump($response);
```

O resultado da execução acima é:

https://api.github.com/users/nategood

Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/projeto_01/httpful.phar/Httpful/Request.php on line 202

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela analise que fiz o serviço da API obriga a que exista um `User-Agent` definido (acredito que o problema provém daí), esta abordagem não envolve `\Httpful\Request` e até acredito que não seja necessário:

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'header'=> "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:10\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$response = file_get_contents('https://api.github.com/users/nategood', false, $context);
```

Em que o conteudo de `$response` vai ser:

> { "login": "nategood", "id": 154115, "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/154115?v=3", "gravatar_id": "", "url": "https://api.github.com/users/nategood", "html_url": "https://github.com/nategood", "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/nategood/followers", "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/nategood/following{/other_user}", "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/nategood/gists{/gist_id}", "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/nategood/starred{/owner}{/repo}", "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/nategood/subscriptions", "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/nategood/orgs", "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/nategood/repos", "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/nategood/events{/privacy}", "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/nategood/received_events", "type": "User", "site_admin": false, "name": "Nate Good", "company": "ShowClix, Inc.", "blog": "http://nategood.com", "location": "Pittsburgh, PA", "email": "code@nategood.com", "hireable": null, "bio": "CTO @Showclix, Founder of @Firstbytes ", "public_repos": 34, "public_gists": 7, "followers": 124, "following": 25, "created_at": "2009-11-16T23:42:29Z", "updated_at": "2017-01-03T14:06:12Z" }

Depois acredito que saibas o que fazer com isto, ex: `json_decode($response, true);` para transformar num array etc...

Também podes fazer com curl:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.github.com/users/nategood');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1');
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, funcionou agora, porém funcionou utilizando a rede do meu celular, na rede da minha empresa não funciona.

Comment: A sério? tentaste esta solução na rede da tua empresa e não funcionou? O que apareceu? @EdsonAlanis

Comment: Mesmo poblema de timeout, o estranho é que se conecto na internet pela rede do celular funciona.


Warning:  file_get_contents(https://api.github.com/users/nategood): failed to open stream: Uma tentativa de conex�o falhou porque o componente conectado n�o respondeu
corretamente ap�s um per�odo de tempo ou a conex�o estabelecida falhou
porque o host conectado n�o respondeu.
 in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto_01\teste-rest.php on line 146



Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto_01\teste-rest.php on line 146

Comment: @EdsonAlanis, e se tentar aceder diretamente pelo browser?

Comment: se eu tentar abrir o https://api.github.com/users/nategood no browser funciona

Comment: É estranho, mas sendo assim não estou mesmo a ver o que possa, sem ver os headers da requisição/resposta é dificil @EdsonAlanis

Comment: como faço para pegar a informação que você precisa? Estou aprendendo a trabalhar com PHP então não tenho muito conhecimento ainda.

Comment: Corres um linux @EdsonAlanis? Experimenta colocar isto no terminal: `curl -v https://api.github.com/users/nategood`

Comment: Não, eu utilizo o Windows

Comment: E se tentares aqui: https://www.hurl.it/ , eu tentei e resultou bem @EdsonAlanis. Acrscentei na resposta uma alternativa que pode ser que funcione

Comment: Pois é, por este site funciona sem problemas, agora na minha aplicação não.

Comment: Tenta essa alternativa que eu acrescentei @EdsonAlanis. Eu até acho que é por o ip daí blacklisted no servidor da API, isso pode acontecer se virem que há requests a mais, ou desconfiarem que estás a tentar alguma coisa menos boa

Comment: C:\Users\Edson Alanis\Desktop\curl-7.46.0-win64\bin>curl -v https://api.github.com/users/nategood
*   Trying 192.30.253.117...
                                                                                            * connect to 192.30.253.117 port 443 failed: Timed out
*   Trying 192.30.253.116...
* connect to 192.30.253.116 port 443 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to api.github.com port 443: Timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to api.github.com port 443: Timed out

Comment: @EdsonAlanis, não faço ideia do que possa ser, visto que no browser consegues sem problema, isso aqui funciona sem probs, e no teu tele também funciona

Comment: será algum bloqueio na rede aqui da empresa?

Comment: Não sei, até porque do browser tu consegues sem problema certo? @EdsonAlanis

Comment: Exatamente, via browser funciona

Answer (score -1):

Para testar, tenta permitir a origem:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); // libera acesso de todos os sites
```

Caso dê certo, substitua o asterisco pela URL do domínio que está utilizando.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.seu_site.com', false);
```

Além disso, cheque se o certificado SSL é válido e se a versão do mesmo é suportada.